# Cannot run conjure-up due to LXD permission denied error

Tags: juju, openstack, lxd, conjure-up

I did follow the instructions:
http://conjure-up.io/docs/users/

but step two works with default values and step 3 fails with the below:

any ideas how to get setup LXD properly. Wiki?

```
INITIALIZING MODEL
                     Press (Q) to cancel bootstrap and exit.

    Please wait while Juju bootstraps the model.                            



                  Oops, there was a problem with your install:  

  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

      Reason:                                                             
        ERROR invalid config: can't connect to the local LXD server:    
        Permisson denied, are you in the lxd group?Please configure LXD 
        by running:?$ newgrp lxd?$ lxd init                             



  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

                                [ Quit         ]
```

Comment: It might help to clarify your question a bit... I'm not quite sure what you're asking...

Comment: I would like to build an openstack install ontop of LXD using conjure-up. but following the instruction -- LXD install suceeds in step2. So far so good. Step 3 -- openstack using LXD fails with the error message attached in my inital quesiton. so what went wrong here? I guess it is on the LXD side of the house but I dont know

Comment: Ok, starting to get you now.  Try putting yourself in the LXD group : `sudo usermod -a -G lxd userName`, replacing userName with your user name.

Comment: solved :-) it -- thx

Comment: I did all of the above but get still get the same error(s).  Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/lxd
Before you run `comjure-up openstack`, you have to run `sudo lxd init`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your user isn't part of the LXD group.  Add your user to the LXD group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lxd username
```

...replacing `username` with your username.

Comment: Hi, please mark this as the answer as you were not originally in the lxd group after configuring lxd itself.

Comment: You talking to the post author?

Comment: Yea, sorry, oliver funk please mark this as the answer

Comment: Sure, no problem.  I'm guessing he's moved on, but it's not serious.  This seems to be his only activity, and he didn't reply to the comments I posted about 30 seconds after his.